# Custom SoftKeyboard, how to put both lowercase and uppercase letters?

Tags: android, keyboard, uppercase, lowercase

I need to create this keyboard for my application:[image]

and so I've implemented this custom keyboard layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="33%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" />
        <Key android:codes="75" android:keyLabel="°" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" />
        <Key android:codes="39" android:keyLabel="'" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" />
        <Key android:codes="97" android:keyLabel="&quot;" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="34" android:keyLabel="," android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="67" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete" />|
        <Key android:codes="0x0008" android:keyLabel="-" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

the big problem is that some characters are lowercase and others uppercase (for example: ' is lowercase, " is uppercase) and so I try to sum the shift-value plus the value in lowercase but it doesn't work.. I search how to do it but I didn't found nothing about...

Anyone know a way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly do you mean?
By the way this lines keyLabel `<Key android:codes="34" android:keyLabel="," android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />` is not right. For ASCII code 34 you have this " character, not this , (this one is number 44)

Comment: I know, I'm trying only to get works the characters °, ' and " for now (that there are most critics for my application)